# Parsing JSON in Python

Tags: python, json, parsing

I have below query stored in a variable I got and I need to fetch value of 'resource_status'.

I need 'UPDATE_IN_PROGRESS'

As requested, putting the code here. The variable evntsdata is storing the events list.

```
try:
    evntsdata = str(hc.events.list(stack_name)[0]).split(" ") # this is the variable that is getting the JSON response (or so) 

    #print(evntsdata[715:733])
    #event_handle = evntsdata[715:733]

    if event_handle == 'UPDATE_IN_PROGRESS':
        loopcontinue = True
        while loopcontinue:
            evntsdata = str(hc.events.list(stack_name)[0]).split(" ")
            #event_handle = evntsdata[715:733]
            if (event_handle == 'UPDATE_COMPLETE'):
                loopcontinue = False
                print(str(timestamp()) + " " + "Stack Update is Completed!" + ' - ' + evntsdata[-3] + ' = ' + evntsdata[-1])
            else:
                print(str(timestamp()) + " " + "Stack Update in Progress!" + ' - ' + evntsdata[-3] + ' = ' + evntsdata[-1])
                time.sleep(10)
    else:
        print("No updates to perform")
        exit(0)

except AttributeError as e:
   print(str(timestamp()) + " " + "ERROR: Stack Update Failure")
   raise
```

print(evntsdata) has below result

```
   ['<Event', "{'resource_name':", "'Stackstack1',", "'event_time':", "'2017-05-26T12:10:43',", "'links':", "[{'href':", "'x',", "'rel':", "'self'},", "{'href':", "'x',", "'rel':", "'resource'},", "{'href':", "'x',", "'rel':", "'stack'}],", "'logical_resource_id':", "'Stackstack1',", "'resource_status':", "'UPDATE_IN_PROGRESS',", "'resource_status_reason':", "'Stack", 'UPDATE', "started',", "'physical_resource_id':", "'xxx',", "'id':", "'xxx'}>"]
```

Comment: This isn't JSON. Looks like you've printed some Event object. Please *show your code* with an [edit] and also include your attempts at parsing this

Comment: please check the edit. Let me know if you need any other info

Comment: Whatever `hc.events.list(stack_name)[0]` is you should not `str()` and `.split()` it. This is wrong on so many levels. I assume this `Event` class has some methods to retrieve the field you are looking for. Use them.

Comment: Yes, the other info would be a [mcve]. Please read carefully and edit again. What is `hc`, for example?

Comment: I have imported hc as a variable from heatclient which one of the packages in Openstack

Comment: You want to get rid of the `<Event ... >` envelope and then call `json.loads` on the rest of the string, then just access it as normal object.

Comment: @freakish, I am out of ways but let me see if there is event class for this

Comment: @liborm, any idea how to remove <Event...> ?

Comment: @liborm it's still not json. Json uses double quotes

Comment: Ok, another take, which still does not qualify as full answer - it seems that you're looking for quite unique strings - what about straight string matching without any further parsing? (`s.find('UPDATE_IN_PROGRESS') != -1`)

Comment: @HeenashreeKhandelwal Do not listen to that. This is wrong. This `Event` object has to have this dictionary inside. You just need a way to retrieve it. Usually you look for something like `.data` or `.content`. You seriously want to `str` it, do shenanigans to remove the envelope and then parse it (which will be hard since this is not JSON)? This is plainly stupid. Read the documentation of this `Event` class and try to retrieve the data properly.

Comment: Of course it is also possible that the authors of the library wanted to hide this data from the user. You can ignore their wishes and dig through the source code to retrieve it anyway. But there also might be a reason (unknown to us) to not do that. You should be careful.

Comment: Agree to @freakish, I was just little ignorant to start my crystal ball to find out what OP might be really trying to do;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not serialize and parse objects when the data is in front of you. This is inefficient and hard to understand and maintain. The solution is quite trivial:

```
data = hc.events.list(stack_name)[0].to_dict()
event_handle = data['resource_status']
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not JSON, [it's a class that you've printed](https://github.com/openstack/python-heatclient/blob/master/heatclient/v1/events.py)

```
class Event(base.Resource):
    def __repr__(self):
        return "<Event %s>" % self._info
```

Try poking around the source code to get access to the **dictionary** `self._info`, then access your fields according

For example,

```
event_info = hc.events.list(stack_name)[0]._info
event_handle = event_info['resource_status']
```

Though, there may be another way like calling `to_dict()` instead, since the underscore indicates a private variable

Comment: The only thing I would not do is to use `_info` (which suggests its a private object). Actually this `Event` class does have a proper `to_dict()` method.

Comment: I didn't bother looking at the base class

Comment: This is so tricky. This github link has that actual code but I really didnt want to go that far. I just want the resource status. https://github.com/openstack/python-heatclient/blob/master/heatclient/v1/events.py.

Comment: Sometimes you need to actually read the documentation (code included) to get your information